# Determine type of 2 corresponding sets

Tags: arrays, list, types, ocaml

I have declared a variable `al : 'a list`, a function `a_to_b : 'a -> 'b` and a function `score : 'b -> int`. Then `let bl = List.map a_to_b al in ...` in the following code defines `bl : 'b list`.

```
let find_best (bl : 'b list) : 'b =
  let score_best, b_best = List.fold_left
    (fun (score_old, b_old) b_new ->
       let score_new = score b_new in
       if score_old < score_new then 
          (score_new, b_new) else 
          (score_old, b_old))
    (score (List.hd bl), List.hd bl) bl in
  b_best

let bl = List.map a_to_b al in
find_best bl
```

This piece of code finds a `b_best` such that its `score` is greatest. But one of my needs is that I also want to know, which `a_best` generates this `b_best` via `a_to_b`, and there is no way. For instance, if `b_best` is the 4th element in the `bl`, I consider the 4th elment of `al` is what I want to get.

I don't want to add more parameters to the function `find_best`. My question is if there is a conventional way to define the type of `al` and `bl`, to make it easy to trace `a_best` from `b_best`, for instance, using `array` instead of `list`? or convert to `array` then convert to `list` back?

Comment: By the way, the correct name for the `find_best` function would be `argmax` : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
let abl = List.combine bl al in (* ('b * 'a) list *)
let a_best = List.assoc b_best abl (* returns the value associated to b_best *)
```

Comment: This, of course, assumes that type `b` supports `=`. `List.assq` might be a better option (and also a tad faster).

Answer (score 2):

In many situations I'd just define `b_best` to take a list of pairs and return a pair.  It would be polymorphic in the second element of the pairs:

```
let find_best (bl : ('b * 'a) list) : 'b * 'a =
  let score_best, ba_best = List.fold_left
    (fun (score_old, (b_old, a_old)) (b_new, a_new) ->
       let score_new = score b_new in
       if score_old < score_new then 
          (score_new, (b_new, a_new)) else 
          (score_old, (b_old, a_old)))
    (score (List.hd bl), List.hd bl) bl in
  ba_best
```

(Or you could define it to take two lists, but this seems to be even less like what you're asking for.)

Under the constraints you state, `find_best` has no access to `al`, so it seems like you have to return an index and use `List.nth` afterwards to retrieve the value from `al`.  If you need to do this a lot with long lists, `List.nth` might be too slow, and so you might want to use an array for `al`.